# Application Server for AutoCAD and some other heavy applications.

Tags: thin-client, application-server, autocad

In a civil engineering firm, there are 6 desktop computers (Dual core 2.6GHz CPU with 3GB of RAM). Each of them are running the following applications: Etabs, SaFe, AutoCAD, 3DMax, Sap, Office on Microsoft Windows. We are currently thinking about upgrading these desktop PCs to Corei7 CPUs with more amount of RAM. But is it a better and more economic idea to buy and install an application server to run all these soft wares in a single server and all the clients access to this server remotely using thin clients (just terminals)? Will we have a better performance? What's your idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you find that it is very difficult to get a terminal server / VDI setup to perform well for those types of applications (AutoCAD, 3DMax).  I suspect you will also find it very costly to get started on a TS/VDI setup for only 6 machines.  You need a lot of server infrastructure to support either of those technologies.  You can and possibly should investigate the costs, but my gut feeling is that it won't even be close if you are limiting the scope to only those machines.